# iOS/php: communicating with database

Tags: php, ios

I am grabbing some data to put in my iOS app by visiting an url. But now, given the URL, the users can access the content of my application without using it. Is there a way to hide the info on this URL from public?

The content I get is through a php script to get the database queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a security system on your website and connect to it using a special URL with an encoded variable.

For example you can make your iOS application connect to :

http://mywebsite.com/somepage.php?id=yuw7262

Then in your PHP page, you can get the value of "id", decipher it and if it is valid, allow the user to go forward. It is pidgin security but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Put some security in your php scripts.

Use `$_SESSION`s to verify that a user is logged in and is using your app correctly

Comment: well you need some sort of security. cookie, session cookie etc